# How do I write statusbar in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, statusbar, jtextpane

When I click in `JTextPane` html content, that html element name should be in statusbar. How can I write stausbar in `JTextPane`? If you have any sample code provide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the example http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html
as a basement of your status bar code.